# Find the right node with xpath

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a table containing tds like the one below.
Im trying to get a hold of the href-part only.
Now i got something like this:

```
var aTags = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td//a[@href]");
```

It seems to be returning all the info in the td. How can I specify that I only want that href? There are many similar questions here but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <a shape="rect" id="ctl00_mainCPH_ResultListUC_ResultList_ctl04_hlRubrik" href="/sitevision/proxy/4.38a41afd11d99fbdb65800016.html/svid12_38a41afd11d99fbdb65800021/-123388378/Standard/Platsannonser/VisaFritextAnnonser.aspx?ids=2499859&amp;q=s%28sn%28systemutvecklare%29sida%281%29ar%2820%29%29" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;">Systemutvecklare</a>
    </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

. Every objects has for example an outerHtml-property looking like the a tag above,
     what I need is yo get the hrefs and collect sthem in a list of strings..
The image below shows that the value i want actually exists in the objects im getting, i want the value of the hrefs...
[image] 
EDIT:
I seem to be able to get the innerhtml like this:

```
var bTags = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td//a/@href").Select(o => o.InnerHtml).ToList();
```

But I still dont know how to get the hrefs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to do what i wanted:

```
var bTags = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td//a/@href").Select(o => o.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath will get you all `a` elements that have an attribute named `href`. To get the attribute itself, you need to use `//td//a/@href`.